# Infinite access token *without* requiring user to "allow access" - in response to Facebook deprecating offline_access

Tags: facebook, access-token, offlineapps

This is a common scenario, but one that I don't see a lot of people posting about. Let's say I have a website, example.com, that loads a list of events from a Facebook Page. It would be a bad user experience to ask the user to "allow access" to the website just so they can see a list of events.

So, what I do is generate an access token with offline access permissions via the Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). This gives me an infinite (as long as the user doesn't change their password, etc.) access token. Perfect.

**Soon, though, Facebook is deprecating offline_access. Is there going to be any way to continue to show this events feed on my website without requiring a user to allow access (which would refresh the access token)?**

Answer (score 1):

No, there will be no more infinite access tokens.  You should store the list of events in your database so you don't have to query facebook so often.  This way the user doesn't have to allow access to see a list of events that you get from your data store.

Comment: Just noticed I hadn't responded to this, sorry for the delay. Anyway, if it even matters anymore (haven't worked with the Facebook API or plugins for several months now), this wouldn't work, because I still want to get the latest list of events when a user visits. I'd be OK with caching them somewhere for a small period of time, but eventually I need a new list, and querying FB could end up prompting the user. So we'd be back to square one.